# Windows task scheduler not reporting errors?

Tags: windows, exception, scheduled-tasks

We have a "service" that is actually nothing more than a C# console app running periodically as a Windows Scheduled Task.

On purpose, we would let the exceptions, if any, bubble up to the main course execution of the program, so that the Windows Task Scheduler could detect this and provide detailed information for the people in charge of monitoring the servers. The application itself is not complex, and does, in fact, make sense to halt all its execution when an error is encountered.

However, we have just found an error because of its side effects of the service not running, and trying to troubleshoot, the people in charge of these servers told me that the only information that they get on this task is its start and end time, no extra information about *how* did it run.

Is this correct? Or **am I supposed to do anything else than just bubble up the exception so that WTS can get detailed information of the task result?**